# Sap odata: Export a single Variable with abap

Tags: abap, sap-gateway

I have got a function module that counts some variables in sap system and export it as single INT4. But when I try to use this in gateway service, it says me 
"no output table mapped" How can i overcome it, I tried to put this variable in a table and export then but I couldnt.

```
DATA: EV_ENQ TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF seqg3.

CALL FUNCTION 'ENQUEUE_READ'
  EXPORTING
    guname = '*'
  IMPORTING
    number = EV_TABLESIZE
  TABLES
    enq = EV_ENQ.
```

`Ev_Tablesize` is the variable that I want to export. It holds the total lock count.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter should be mapped under your service implementation in SEGW. If it is not, then you should map them again and be sure that the parameter is being displayed.[image]

Comment: In my project the parameter isn't in a table thats why i'm struggling. So as I understand I cant use it without table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Oğuz.

Comment: I believe, you can. I assume you are calling 'ENQUEUE_READ' function in your RFC that called by the (odata) service. You can define an export parameter to your RFC and map it to the service. Thus, you will be able to pass Ev_Tablesize parameter.